# JSON Post from C# to a ColdFusion API

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to connect to an API that requires JSON and I keep receiving a 500 internal error. After reading the connection instructions again it looks like my issue stems from the fact that I am passing a string and the API is looking for a form field with the string as a value. How is this done programatically in c#? The below is not working for me.

```
 //Create JSON string to send to iCohere API using POST
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.api,url");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"],
                AuthCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthCode"],
                cSeq = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cSeq"],
                LastName = "Fett",
                FirstName = "Bubba",
                EmailAddress = "dec18@comingsoon.com",
                EventCode = "WEBINAR"
            });

            TextBox iCohereForm = new TextBox();
            iCohereForm.ID = "JSONAPISTR";
            iCohereForm.Text = json;
            streamWriter.Write(iCohereForm);

        }


        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of TextBox class. Or it's a part of Windows Forms/WPF, is it ?

Comment: Since the API is looking for the JSON string in a form field I created the Textbox programmatically using the standard namespace System.Web.UI.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** The appropriate place for this question is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

The issue is that you trying put your UI control object into StreamWriter.
And use this memory stream data during making a HTTP request.
Also you are doing HTTP request in wrong way. The correct one is:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            ClientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"],
            AuthCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthCode"],
            cSeq = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cSeq"],
            LastName = "Fett",
            FirstName = "Bubba",
            EmailAddress = "dec18@comingsoon.com",
            EventCode = "WEBINAR"
        });

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api url");
requst.Method = "POST";
requst.ContentType = "application/json";
byte[] _byteVersion = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);

request.ContentLength = _byteVersion.Length

Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(_byteVersion, 0, _byteVersion.Length);
stream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Comment: I had it that way to start, but the API wasn't working and after reading the instructions again it states that it requires that the string value be sent in a form field called "JSONAPISTR". That was why I tried adding it as a value to a TextBox.

Comment: Well I got it to work by simply changing what is sent in Stream.Write.  streamWriter.Write("JSONAPISTR=" + json); worked like a charm.

Comment: @ChrisLombardi yep, as I said, you just sent wrong object to your Stream.